# mount.exe not found when run from a Java Process

Tags: java, windows, mount

I'm trying to execute a mount command as a Java Process. The following is how I form the command:

```
List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();

command.add("cmd.exe");
command.add("/c");
command.add("mount.exe");
command.add("-u:" + username);
command.add("-p:" + password); 
command.add(IP + ":" + mountPoint);
command.add(driveLetter + ":");

ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);

processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

When I execute this, I get the error that,

```
'mount.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I've mount.exe installed and the path is set in the environment variable,

```
C:\>where mount.exe
C:\Windows\System32\mount.exe

C:\>path
PATH=C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows; ... [removed the remaining entries]
```

When I execute the command manually at the command prompt, it works fine:

```
C:\>cmd.exe /c mount.exe -u:<user> -p:<password> <IP>:<mount point> Z:
```

I would be grateful if someone can point out what I'm missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with running *mount* and *unmount* on Windows Server 2008 **x64** from TeamCity Build Agent (works as a service, runs as System user).
Script works fine when I run it from user session by clicking the .cmd file, but when TeamCity Build Agent tries to run it, I see the very same error:

> 'C:\Windows\System32\umount.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Now I have the solution.

*mount* **works** when you run it with C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe, because *cmd* searches for *mount* in C:\Windows\System32\

*mount* **fails** when you run it with c:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe, because this *cmd* searches for *mount* in c:\Windows\SysWOW64\

Answer (score 0):

See what happens when you write the full path for mount.exe in your command.add() calls. I may be wrong about this, but I think that when you call cmd.exe from within a command prompt yourself, the environment variables are passed automatically to the called program. This may not be happening correctly using ProcessBuilder, and if the full path works, it might be an indication of that.

Comment: I tried, that doesn't help either.
    `'C:\Windows\System32\mount.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`
 
BTW, the same program works in another windows machine; both have Windows Server 2008 R2.